# Is there any advantage for killing Paarthurnax?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What will I stand to gain from killing Paarthurnax and getting back in good standing with the Blades?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/43994/what-will-i-stand-to-gain-from-killing-paarthurnax-and-getting-back-in-good-stan)

What are the advantages/disadvantages for completing this quest?