# How can I cancel the quest to kill Paarthurnax?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

When the blades ask you to kill Paarthurnax (the dragon or the leader of the Greybeards) where are they located so that I can cancel that mission and tell them that I don't want to kill him.

Comment: There is a Mod for the PC that offers alternatives.

Comment: Related: [What will I stand to gain from killing Paarthurnax and getting back in good standing with the Blades?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/43994/4797)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can ignore that quest and continue.  Killing paathurnax will fix your status with the Blades, but the Greybeards will no longer help you.  Not killing will cause the Blade to not help you.

Answer (score 7):

You can't. You have to go confront Paarthurnax to continue the main story. There is no way to cancel this quest.

However, Paarthurnax speaks to you and offers you alternatives to killing him, which you may take him up on.

Comment: So does that mean that when i talk to him it says that i'm not going to kill him that i can't finish the quest?

Comment: @JamesBond Talking to Paarthurnax resolves the quest regardless of how the conversation with him goes.

Comment: @JamesBond If you don't like the outcome of not killing him, there are mods to resolve this forced choice.

Comment: This quest is in no way required for the main story to continue.  The Blades are pissed of that you've been conspiring with one of his kind. You can avoid the quest, leaving them pissed off.  You can confront Paarthurnax and choose to have either the Blades or the Geybeards pissed of at you for the remainder of the game.  One way or the other you choose.

Answer (score 4):

If you are trying to play through the Blades' storyline without killing Paarthurnax, you simply can't.

It's a choice you need to make in the game. It's like going with the Imperials versus the Stormcloaks. You just have to choose.

Either way, you're not really missing out on much. Both the Greybeards and Esbern will give you locations of word walls. The Blades are a bit more interactive, though (recruiting followers, dragon-killing missions, the like).

---

If you were on the PC, there is a neat little mod called (aptly) [The Paarthurnax Dilemma](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/18465/?). This mod would allow you to play both sides of the fence: Paarthurnax can live, but you can still play the Blades questline.

Comment: Cross-posted from [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/233005/76693) as per Timelord64's request.

Comment: [The Parthumax Dilemma](https://bethesda.net/en/mods/skyrim/mod-detail/2940699) is also available on XBox One.

Answer (score -2):

If you try to kill him while he is still essential (while you still need him) get his health down to zero and before his health regenerates fast travel to sky haven temple and it should say that he died